# Why I am getting syntax error while declaring System properties for gecko driver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have written this code to make Firefox Driver. But Eclipse is throwing error at line stating: System.setProperty.

Following is the error:
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
    - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
     QualifiedName
    - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
     MethodHeaderName
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
    - Syntax error on token ",", < expected
I have already correctly set Build path and JARs. Still I am getting this error.

```
package testing;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Login {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "G:\\JARs\\geckodriver.exe");

}
```

Comment: You must call this code from inside a method. You must create a method and put your code in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your code does not include a main method.
It should be something like this:

```
package testing;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Login {

    public static final main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "G:\\JARs\\geckodriver.exe");
    }

}
```

Comment: Got it. What a silly mistake I made. Thanks for prompt answer.